# How does glucose delivered intraperitoneal (i.p.) get into the peripheral circulation?

Tags: physiology, pharmacology, anatomy, lymphatic-system

Intraperitoneal delivery of drugs or fluids is something that occurs much more frequently in veterinary medicine than clinical medicine. In veterinary medicine or scientific studies using animals, compounds are frequently given via this route that it is typically referred to as "[i.p. injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraperitoneal_injection)" or "i.p. delivery".

**When glucose is delivered via this route (by injection or catheter directly into the peritoneal space), *how does the glucose actually get into the systemic circulation? That is, where does it actually go anatomically?***

I can't find much data on this or an explanation that is collectively agreed upon. In particular for drug studies, some people say that the drugs or metabolites get into the [portal circulation of the liver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatic_portal_system), while other people say that the drugs are absorbed by the [peritoneum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peritoneum) and enter the systemic circulation via the [lymphatic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphatic_system)? Some individuals would argue that substances diffuse across the peritoneal membrane and then make their way into the interstitial fluid first, and then passively diffuse into the body's fluid compartments. Could it be another route? Could it be an active process or is it completely passive? Or, alternatively, could it be a combination of several of these processes?

Comment: Just a guess (which is why this isn't an answer), but I would suspect that the mechanism strongly depends on the compound(s) being injected. For example, small molecule drugs may be much more likely to diffuse across membranes than to require some sort of active transport mechanism. However, some proteins such as antibodies can usually get into the peripheral circulation fairly easily, whereas other proteins cannot (personal experience).

Comment: @MattDMo most definitely and worthy as an answer. This question is too broad imo. By adding a compound, or class of chemically related compounds will make it better answerable other than with an "it depends" answer. As of now MattDMO 's comment makes a fine answer.

Comment: @MattDMo agree with your comment above... but I want to find evidence of the actual route that a compound like glucose would take to get into the peripheral circulation - like when we inject mice i.p. with a glucose solution for a glucose tolerance test - the glucose molecule diffuses across the peritoneal membrane, but then where does it go? Does it just diffuse into the capillaries and then diffuse into the hepatic portal circulation? I don't know where to find that information - a lot of people refer to that as "common knowledge" - but that must be cited somewhere

Comment: @Christiaan - thanks for your comment - will change to glucose specifically  to address your concern.